# How does the recurring task “misses” four invocations completely in example below?

Tags: java, timertask

An abstract from JCIP-

> If a recurring TimerTask is scheduled to run every 10 ms and another
>   Timer-Task takes 40 ms to run, the recurring task either (depending on
>   whether it was scheduled at fixed rate or fixed delay) gets called
>   four times in rapid succession after the long-running task completes,
>   or “misses” four invocations completely.

I understand that since the first task is scheduled to run after every 10ms, so within 40 ms, it will be executed 4 times.

But what does the author meant by  **misses four invocations completely ?**

Comment: That you expect it to be called every 10ms, but for a window when the timer was busy with another task, it was never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example in code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    // Schedule a new task that runs at a 10ms interval and stars immediately
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("10ms delayed task ran at " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        }
    }, 0, 10);

    // Schedule a task to start in 50ms that takes 40ms to run.
    // It cancels itself so it's only run once.
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("slow task ran at " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(40);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            this.cancel();
        }
    }, 50, 10);

    // Wait 100 ms for the demo to end, then stop the timer.
    Thread.sleep(100);
    timer.cancel();
}
```

Output:

```
10ms delayed task ran at 1
10ms delayed task ran at 11
10ms delayed task ran at 22
10ms delayed task ran at 32
10ms delayed task ran at 42
slow task ran at 52
10ms delayed task ran at 92
```

Answer (score 1):

So, there are two tasks. Task One which is scheduled to run every 10ms and Task Two which takes 40ms to run.

Let's say at time 0, Task Two starts running and immediately afterwards, Task One is triggered:

0.0: Task 2 running

0.1: Task 1 triggered, Task 2 still running.

10.1: Task 1 triggered, Task 2 still running

20.1 Task 1 triggered, Task 2 still running

30.1 Task 1 triggered, Task 2 still running

40.0: Task 2 finishes, Task 1 starts running.

As you can see, from when Task 2 starts to when Task 2 ends, Task 1 was triggered 4 times without getting a chance to run. 
Also, Task 1 will run 4 times in rapid succession, since it was triggered 4 times but hadn't gotten a chance to run.

Comment: You mean there is only a single thread and hence when the same was occupied with Task 2, it missed the task1 even though task 1 was triggered.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari Even if you have multiple threads, only one can run at a time unless you also have multiple CPUs. So, if the Task 2 thread has higher priority than the Task 1 thread, the same thing could happen in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: No, actually it wouldn't. Thread handling is done by the operating system, and it slices the tasks differently and allows them to operate concurrently. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to have any concurrency - not in Java nor anywhere.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I think you are assuming you know how every OS handles "threads" and that there is a difference between a "thread" and a "task" on all OSes. If a task/thread has very high priority, and is always active, on some OSes, there will be no concurrency, because it blocks every other task/thread.

Comment: @iheanyi In all modern OSs that support Java, there is.

Comment: @RealSkeptic so you are claiming that "thread starvation" is not an issue in any OS that supports Java?

Comment: Not because of any single other thread, it isn't. Starvation may occur when there are many competing threads, not just two.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Umm, what OS guarantees it can protect from a programmer writing two threads where one starves the other?